# How to identify variables with the same identifier in different subViews

Tags: swift3

First post and I'll be honest, I'm pretty bad at coding. I'm working with Swift 3 for a school project and I have a question.

I'm creating multiple subviews through a for in loop through an array...

...and each created subview contains one programmatically created label, each with a different word, and a programmatically created UI Tap Gesture attached to each view...

```
Import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecongizerDelegate 
{
var array = ["Each","One","Has","Its","Own","Name"]
var label = UILabel()
var DynamicView = UIView()
var count = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

createSubView()

//end SuperView
}

func createSubview()
 {
  for thing in array {
var string = array[count]
count = count + 1
DynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 160))
            DynamicView.center = CGPoint(x: xV,y: yV)
            DynamicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)

label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 100, height: 21))
            label.center = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 13)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 13)
            label.text = "\(string)"
            self.DynamicView.addSubview(label)

 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
  #selector(ViewController.tapped(recignizer:)))

            DynamicView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            DynamicView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)



}
 }
func tapped (recignizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("\(label.text!)")
    }

}
```

... (I'm excluding the code that separates all the views from being stacked on top of each other, so please assume that these views are spaced out, and this list of views is in a scroll view in my actual code, just not cramming that spaghetti code in here)...

...The result of the code is a layout of subViews, each with its own label that is a different word, and a tap gesture for each subView which triggers a function...

...What I want is a way to tap on each subview and find what the text in the label is. As of right now, when you tap on a view, you get what the label.text was in the last View made, so the result of print("label.text!") --> 'Name' , which makes some sense.

Is there any possible way to find the specific labels text even though they are all called "Label"?

I'm not looking to do a collection view or anything of the sort, I need something of this sort of coding to get what I need done.

Thank you to whoever helped this foolish swift student, sorry that my Swift lingo is hot garbage like my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are initializing the same `DynamicView` and `label` inside the for loop so it will overwrite and it will have last value from the array. To solved the problem you need to create separate UIView and separate UILabel in for loop. Also you need to set userInteraction of label to true because by default its false.

```
for thing in array {
   let dynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 160))
        dynamicView.center = CGPoint(x: xV,y: yV)
        dynamicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.view.addSubview(dynamicView)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 100, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 60, y: 13)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 13)
        label.text = thing
        self.dynamicView.addSubview(label)
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(ViewController.tapped(recignizer:)))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Now your all view’s `origin` is `CGPoint.zero` so only last view label will visible and when you tap on label to get text of its you can get this way.

```
func tapped(recignizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let tappedLabel = recignizer.view as? UILabel {
         print("\(tappedLabel.text)”)
    }
}
```

Comment: I just it now, but the "if let tappedLabel = recignizer.view as? UILabel" ends up as a nil value.

Comment: @penguini Add gesture to `UILabel` instead of `uiview` and you all set to go.